# How to transform one object to another in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a small game which is pretty much finished. The thing is it didn't have any menus or game over acreens and the like. Everything used to be in a single class Game which had all the logic and rendering. To make the menus possible I created a State class and now there is a StateGame, StateMenu, ... The problem is that I don't know how to switch one state to the other. Currently the State class has a method `switchTo: (State*)new state`. In the method I put:

```
[self release];
self = newState;
```

This produces a segfault and I changed it to:

```
State *old = self;
self = newState;
AUTORELEASE (old)
```

This simply doesn't work.

Sorry for the formatting but I'm typing this on a phone, anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Too hard to answer this without more code defining the classes being described here.

Comment: As soon as I get home I'll post the class definitions as well, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably don't want to "change the object to another"... (Not recommended by the way, self = ... bad idea :[ )

What you'll want is a new Class called, ie GameManager. it will have a property that can be Game, a Menu or a GameOver instance. It will work as a state machine (perform action on state changes) and will display, according to the state, a Game, a Menu or a GameOver screen.

Comment: Thanks! I made it so that states themselves are not nesponsible from switching from one to the other. It works now and it makes more sense

Comment: Can you mark the question as solved please, thank you :)